# Создание bitmap из двух bitmap с прозрачностью

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Требуется вывести картинку, которая складывается из 2-х: внизу непрозрачная, сверху прозрачная. Изначально устраивал способ:

```
BitmapDrawable1.SetAlpha (255);
imageView1.SetImageDrawable (BitmapDrawable1);
BitmapDrawable2.SetAlpha ((int)(alpha * 255));
imageView2.SetImageDrawable (BitmapDrawable2);
```

Однако теперь складывать надо не две, а четыре картинки, и расширение такого способа представляется слишком громоздким в реализации.

Хочется понять, как складывать два `BitmapDrawable` в один `BitmapDrawable`. Или два `Bitmap` в один.

Код на c# под xamarin.

Comment: Почему метка "java" если код на c#?

Comment: большинство разработчиков под андроид имеют дело с явой, А мне нужны именно люди знающие андроид

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле суть решения в том, что Drawable - это объект который умеет рисовать на Canvas. Нет никакой проблемы последовательно рисовать на Canvas объекты, просто методы BitmapDrawable.draw(Canvas) друг после друга запускайте и все.

Можно просто создать Bitmap, получить у него Canvas, на нем отрисовать последовательно, потом этот Bitmap разместить на ImageView.

Можно сделать кастомный Drawable, который будет последовательно отрисовывать массив drawable И уже его присвоить imageView вот пример:

```
Drawable[] drawableArray=new Drawable[]{BitmapDrawable1,BitmapDrawable2};       
MultyDrawable=new MultyDrawable(drawableArray);

imageView1.SetImageDrawable (MultyDrawable);

public class MultyDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Drawable[] drawableArray;

    public MultyDrawable(Drawable[] drawableArray) {
        this.drawableArray=drawableArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Drawable each:drawableArray) {
            each.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: хм.. вроде то, что нужно, пойду проверять

Comment: а как получить канвас у произвольного битмапа?

Comment: Или правильнее создать канвас и передать ему битмап уже потом?

Comment: Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap CombBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WidthBmp, HeightBmp, conf); Canvas cc = new Canvas(CombBitmap);   Но это на java, хз как на xamarin, Создавать нужно новый битмап, потому что произвольный Bitmap у тебя не mutable будет.

Comment: Но мне кажется с extends drawable получше будет, битмапы тяжелые много места в оперативке занимают.

Comment: Да, все работает как надо. с разрешением странные вещи стали происходить, пнг 96*96 не помещается в битмап 96*96, а остальное все ок.